# Punctuating "waste not, want not"

Tags: punctuation, commas, dashes

How do you punctuate a sentence to indicate that the second phrase is contingent on the first, e.g. *Waste not, want not*?

You could read this typical punctuation as meaning "waste not and want not" vs. "waste not, and therefore want not". Same for *Well govern, well serve yourself.* Dashes don't work, I don't think.

Comment: I think you've answered your own question in your example (which is usually preceded by **e.g.**, not **EG**). Google Books doesn't index commas, and it's case-insensitive, so if you look at the results for ["Waste not want not"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Waste+not+want+not%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) it should be pretty obvious what *most* writers do.

Comment: You might be interested in the *correlative comparative construction*. E.g. "The older he gets, the more cynical he becomes", "The sooner, the better".

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that the comma in this sentence signifies the separation of two related ideas but more that it puts a reading break between them. "Waste not want not", when spoken would not tell the reader to pause between the two phrases.

"Let's eat grandma." versus "Let's eat, grandma." The comma makes all the difference as in the second sentence the comma creates the reading pause that turns the sentence from being cannibalistic into a request for grandma to come and eat.

The comma is also used in conditionals to separate the condition and consequence. I am no punctuation expert but a comma in "waste not, want not" seems like a sensible thing to have.

Answer (score 0):

The comma is inserted in substitution of a coordinating conjunction (and, but, for, so, or, nor, yet).

Comment: The comma does not substitute for a coordinating conjunction here. You could avoid a comma by expressing it as *One who does not waste does not want*, or you can keep it by expressing it as *If you do not waste, then you will not want*. In any case, a comma is commonly used *with* a coordinating conjunction when joining two clauses.

Comment: Indeed. But commas, generally speaking, can substitute for coordinating conjunctions, in English. Moreover, commas can be equally used with proceeding subordinating conjunctions, too, but aren't always required.

Comment: This is not the place to discuss matters "generally speaking"; we are here to answer the question.

Comment: Well! Aren't you a feisty one! Anyway, I appreciate your exceptional knowledge of English.